# ¿Cómo hago para insertar datos en varias tablas mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, trigger

Tengo dos tablas la primera es `preguntas` y la segunda `respuestas`, lo que quiero es pasar los datos de 1 pregunta y de 4 respuesta, y me inserte todo en una consulta. Si falla alguna que no inserte nada; Y aparte, siempre la primera respuesta que le pase sea la valida. Para que se valida la respuesta debe estar relacionada con la tabla `pregunta` en su campo `pk_respuesta`.

Otra cosa, cada respuesta que se cree esta relacionada de esta manera:

La tabla `respuesta` en su campo `pk_pregunta` esta relacionado con la tabla `pregunta`.

estas son las tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE pregunta (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  pk_materia int(11) NOT NULL,
  pregunta varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  descriccion varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  fecha_registro date NOT NULL,
  pk_respuesta int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

y la otra es:

```
CREATE TABLE `respuestas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pk_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opcion` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
)
```

¿Se puede en mysql o mejor lo hago en el código?

Comment: Lo más simple sería hacerlo con un TRIGGER, aunque faltan detalles importantes en tu pregunta, como qué valores tendrá cada columna, cómo se decide la respuesta correcta, etc... Un TRIGGER es un disparador automático en el cual debes saber de antemano o decidir de algún modo qué valor tendrá cada cosa. Ese es el núcleo de este asunto y es lo que no explicas precisamente. Además de eso, debes mostrar siempre lo que has intentado y en qué punto exactamente te encuentras bloqueado, qué errores tienes, etc... Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Otra alternativa podria ser un PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO en lugar de un TRIGGER. Donde le puedes pasar como parametro la pregunta y las respuestas. Y el procedimiento almacenado insertaria la pregunta y las cuatro respuestas en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

De mi comentario anterior, intento darte un ejemplo con mi idea. Crear un procedimiento almacenado para crear la pregunta y las cuatro respuestas. Evidentemente, tendrás que acabar y adaptar mi ejemplo a tus necesidades.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE crear_pregunta(IN pregunta VARCHAR(255), 
                                IN respuesta1 VARCHAR(255),
                                IN respuesta2 VARCHAR(255),
                                IN respuesta3 VARCHAR(255),
                                IN respuesta4 VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO pregunta (....) VALUES (pregunta,...);
    INSERT INTO respuestas (....) VALUES (respuesta1,...);
    INSERT INTO respuestas (....) VALUES (respuesta2,...);
    INSERT INTO respuestas (....) VALUES (respuesta3,...);
    INSERT INTO respuestas (....) VALUES (respuesta4,...);
END$$
DELIMITER
```

Y luego:

```
CALL crear_pregunta('pregunta bla bla', 'respuesta 1 blabla', ...)
```